# Formato Fecha de una consulta

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo una consulta sql en la cual obtengo fechas... le doy este formato pero me sale el error

```
---- 
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on null in...
```

Mi código es:

```
$FechaInicio = $fila2[FechaInicio]->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: quizas este enlace te pueda ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744943/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-boolean

Comment: Y por que no lo formateas directamente en la consulta SQL ? y si mal no estoy FechaInicio debería ir entre comillas simples!

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción podría ser:

```
$FechaInicio = date('Y-m-d',$fila2['FechaInicio']);
```

[Link de referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)